# 2d arrows forming axis with text

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

The following output under tikz/pgfplots 3.0 is desired:

[image]

I would further like:

(i)  Text (instead of the gradients) at the end of the arrow-tips (sufficient room for writing +/- 10-15 characters per arrow tip)
(ii) Every quadrant to have its own color, that fades into the adjecant quadrants. How to achieve this?

Comment: MWE partially based on p.200 tikz manual `\documentclass{book} \usepackage{pgfplots} \usepackage{tiki} \uselibrary{arrows.meta} \begin{document} \pagestyle{empty} \tikz[very thick] \draw [-Stealth[] . Stealth[] Stealth[]}] (0,0) -- (2,0); \end{document}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you like to have something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm] {standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,fadings,positioning}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = angle 45,
       node distance = 0mm,
mynode/.style n args = {3}{name=n#1,
                           fading angle=#2,
                           fill=#3,
                           scope fading=south, minimum size=33mm, text opacity=1}
                        ]
\node[mynode={1}{45}{red}]                  {indeterminate axis};
\node[mynode={2}{315}{teal},right=of n1]    {left  axis deviation};
\node[mynode={3}{135}{cyan}, below=of n1]   {right axis deviation};
\node[mynode={4}{225}{orange},right=of n3]  {normal axis};
\draw[<->]  (n1.south west) node[left]      {+\SI{180}{\degree}} -- 
            (n2.south east) node[right]     { \SI{0}{\degree}};
\draw[<->]  (n3.south east) node[below]     {+\SI{90}{\degree}} --
            (n1.north east) node[above]     {-\SI{90}{\degree}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**
After sending my answer I discover that `text opacity` doesn't has any effect. If you like to have not faded text in quadrants, than you need to wrote them separately, something like this:

```
mynode/.style n args = {3}{name=n#1,
                           fading angle=#2,
                           fill=#3,
                           scope fading=south, minimum size=33mm,
                           node contents={}}
                        ]
\node[mynode={1}{45}{red}];
\node[mynode={2}{315}{teal},right=of n1];
\node[mynode={3}{135}{cyan},below=of n1];
\node[mynode={4}{225}{orange},right=of n3];
    \node[at=(n1.center)]   {indeterminate axis};
    \node[at=(n2.center)]   {left  axis deviation};
    \node[at=(n3.center)]   {right axis deviation};
    \node[at=(n4.center)]   {normal axis};
```

Also the axes have better look if they are thicker as suggest 'Enthusiastic Student', tor example:

```
\draw[thick,<->]  (n1.south west) node[left]      {+\SI{180}{\degree}} --
            (n2.south east) node[right]     { \SI{0}{\degree}};
\draw[thick,<->]  (n3.south east) node[below]     {+\SI{90}{\degree}} --
            (n1.north east) node[above]     {-\SI{90}{\degree}};
```

Comment: Very nice colouring. I think making the axis's thicker will make the plot more beautiful...

Comment: Whoohoo!! +1! Excellent work.

Answer (score 4):

For merging the colors from each quadrant you could try the `bilinear interpolation` shading although this does not render very well with some `PDF` viewers:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, x=2.5cm, y=2.5cm]    
\path [shading=bilinear interpolation,
  upper left=red,  upper right=green, 
  lower left=blue, lower right=cyan] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\draw [<->] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [<->] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\foreach \text [count=\i] in {-90,+180,+90,0}
  \node [anchor=\i*90+180] at (\i*90:1) {$\text^\circ$};
\foreach \text [count=\i from 0] in {Indeterminate\\axis,Right axis\\deviation,Normal axis,Left axis\\deviation}
  \node [align=center,font=\footnotesize] at (\i*90+135:.75) {\text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is an attempt to get the white "hole" in the middle. I guess this could be done with a fading or something, but I went with a custom postscript shading. I'm not sure the postscript code is quite robust though.

Also the shading has to be stated *after* the keys for setting the corner colors
as these automatically set the shading to `bilinear interpolation`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading[lower left,lower right,upper left,upper right]{bilinear interpolation with white center}
{\pgfpointorigin}
{\pgfpoint{100bp}{100bp}}
{
  \pgfshadecolortorgb{lower left}{\colll}\pgfshadecolortorgb{lower right}{\collr}
  \pgfshadecolortorgb{upper right}{\colur}\pgfshadecolortorgb{upper left}{\colul}
}{
 2 copy
  25 sub 50 div exch 25 sub 50 div 2 copy            
  neg 1 add exch neg 1 add                   
  3 1 roll 2 copy exch 5 2 roll 6 copy 6 copy  
  \colllred mul exch \collrred mul add mul   
  4 1 roll
  \colurred mul exch \colulred mul add mul
  add
  13 1 roll
  \colllgreen mul exch \collrgreen mul add mul   
  4 1 roll
  \colurgreen mul exch \colulgreen mul add mul
  add
  7 1 roll
  \colllblue mul exch \collrblue mul add mul  
  4 1 roll
  \colurblue mul exch \colulblue mul add mul
  add
  5 3 roll
  50 sub 100 div exch 50 sub 100 div  
  dup mul exch dup mul add sqrt 2 sqrt div 5 mul 
  dup neg 1 add exch 2 copy 2 copy 
  9 -1 roll mul add 3 1 roll 7 -1 roll mul add 4 2 roll 5 -1 roll mul add
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, x=2.5cm, y=2.5cm]    
\path [upper left=red,  upper right=green, 
  lower left=blue, lower right=cyan,
  shading=bilinear interpolation with white center] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);

\draw [<->] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [<->] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\foreach \text [count=\i] in {-90,+180,+90,0}
  \node [anchor=\i*90+180] at (\i*90:1) {$\text^\circ$};
\foreach \text [count=\i from 0] in {Indeterminate\\axis,Right axis\\deviation,Normal axis,Left axis\\deviation}
  \node [align=center,font=\footnotesize] at (\i*90+135:.75) {\text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And finally, here is a version that allows the center color to be specified:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading[lower left,lower right,upper left,upper right,center]{bilinear interpolation with center}
{\pgfpointorigin}
{\pgfpoint{100bp}{100bp}}
{
  \pgfshadecolortorgb{lower left}{\colll}\pgfshadecolortorgb{lower right}{\collr}
  \pgfshadecolortorgb{upper right}{\colur}\pgfshadecolortorgb{upper left}{\colul}
  \pgfshadecolortorgb{center}{\colcn}
}{
  2 copy
  % Following is the same as bilinear shading code
  25 sub 50 div exch 25 sub 50 div 2 copy            
  neg 1 add exch neg 1 add                   
  3 1 roll 2 copy exch 5 2 roll 6 copy 6 copy  
  \colllred mul exch \collrred mul add mul   
  4 1 roll
  \colurred mul exch \colulred mul add mul
  add
  13 1 roll
  \colllgreen mul exch \collrgreen mul add mul   
  4 1 roll
  \colurgreen mul exch \colulgreen mul add mul
  add
  7 1 roll
  \colllblue mul exch \collrblue mul add mul  
  4 1 roll
  \colurblue mul exch \colulblue mul add mul
  add
  % Now do the centre...
  5 3 roll
  50 sub 50 div exch 50 sub 50 div  
  dup mul exch dup mul add sqrt 2 mul 
  dup neg 1 add exch 2 copy 2 copy 
  9 -1 roll mul exch \colcnred mul add 
  3  1 roll 
  7 -1 roll mul exch \colcngreen mul add 
  4  2 roll 
  5 -1 roll mul exch \colcnblue mul add
}

\colorlet{center}{white}
\tikzset{center/.code=\colorlet{center}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, x=2.5cm, y=2.5cm]
\foreach \c [count=\i from 0] in {black, white, purple, orange}{   
\path [upper left=red,  upper right=green, 
  lower left=blue, lower right=cyan, center=\c,
  shading=bilinear interpolation with center] ({mod(\i,2)*2.5},{int(\i/2)*2.5}) rectangle ++(2,2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark, I like this. Is it also possible to merge your code (keeping the text-break functionality of your example) with the `[shading=bilinear interpolation,` together with the answer from Zarko. I then have the shadow in the middle of the figure, as well as the blend of the four colors.

Comment: Compliments! The additions are certainly useful. NB In my case I use text at node ends instead of gradients (see i).